Waitress Flask - Can't Connect to API
I'm running waitress for my Flask API and I can't connect to the host.  Here are somethings I've tried:

I've opened port 8080 inbound on the host (I'm not binding to the localhost but to the IP address of the host)
When I host it on my laptop (via Wi-fi), I can't connect to the API (except when I turn off the firewall, then it connects)
When I host the API on my desktop (via Ethernet), I can connect to the API.
I checked both Firewall settings and profiles (both the laptop and desktop are identical)
I turned on the firewall logs and that doesn't give me much info except that the TCP packets are being dropped (src and dest IP addresses are accurate & so is the destination port (8080)

I'm just trying to connect to the API from devices on the network.

so all your problem is firewall, not flask or waitress. It can makes problem because we can't see your firewall and we can't test it.

There was an application (python) rule that was blocking my API call.  I'm not sure how that rule got there.
